# How do i check if a user info is correct python

Tags: python

So i am making a password system. 
It ask for the user to enter the password, then check if it's right. I am getting a error with:

```
 %Run HelloPython.py
  File "/home/pi/Python Coding/HelloPython.py", line 17
    print('Welcome home,', name,)
        ^
SyntaxError: expected an indented block
```

Something is wrong. 
Code:

```
    print('What is your name?')

# Stores everything typed up until ENTER
name = sys.stdin.readline()

print('Hello', name,'Enter password.')
password = sys.stdin.readline()
if password == ("1"):
print('Welcome home,', name,)
    else:
      print("Password:", password,"Is incorect. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SyntaxError: expected an indented block

Indent your `if`-`else` statements like below.

1. To check "is equal to", use `==` instead of `=` which is an assignment.
2. `readline` returns a string, so you should compare it with `'1'` string.
3. `readline` includes a newline `\n` at the end, so call `strip()` on it.

```
import sys

print('What is your name?')

# Stores everything typed up until ENTER
name = sys.stdin.readline()    
print('Hello', name, 'Enter password.')

password = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
if password == '1':
    print("Welcome home,", name)
else:
    print("Password:", password, "Is incorrect. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 2):

So I've re-wrote your code. You're forgetting to indent your if-statements. http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk

```
import sys    # Import the 'sys' module

print('What is your name?')

name = sys.stdin.readline()

print('Hello ', name, '. Enter password.')
password = sys.stdin.readline()

# Use '=='
if password == 1:
    print("Welcome home, ", name)
    # Here you need indentation.
else:
    print("Password: ", password," is incorect. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not your only error, but it is probably the most easily overlooked:

```
if password = 1:
```

What's going on here: 1 is getting stored to the variable `password` (Since `=` is the storing operator). Then `if password` is getting evaluated; variables are truthy in python, so that will evaluate to `True`, regardless of what you had stored in `password` above.

To remedy this, use `==` for comparing `password`, and also since `password` is a string, put the `1` in quotes so that it is compared as a string.

```
if password == "1":
```

You need to fix your indentation as well, python is dependent on whitespace.